# laravel 4.2 regex validation

Tags: php, regex

I have rules for password, the rules is:

```
Only alphanumeric characters, spaces, dashes, periods, and underscores are allowed.
```

in Users model i use validation like bellow

```
'password'=>array('required', 'min:8', 'max:20', 'regex:[A-Za-z\s\-\._]')
```

when the form submitted, it throw error `The password format is invalid.`. what could be wrong with my regex?

PS: i input 12345678 in password field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not including numerical characters in your regexp.

You should add `0-9`, this gives : `regex:[A-Za-z0-9\s\-\._]'`